# A CSS Tetris style puzzle

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

## CLICK FOR PLAYGROUND

---

**CHALLENGE**

Create a two column div layout without any spaces using **CSS**.

**STARTING LAYOUT**

Where each box is simply: `<div class=A1">A1</div>`

[image]

**DESIRED LAYOUT**

[image]

---

**Simple right?**

Well there are conditions:

1. The heights of each div are variable.
2. The number of divs is variable.
3. The height of left and right column should be as equal as possible.
   *(Leaving a minimum amount of trailing white space).*
4. Changing the HTML **is allowed**.
5. The divs do not need to display in order.

**JavaScript solutions are acceptable but the winner will be the genius who can do this with pure CSS.**

**NOTE:** The divs are actually generated using a .NET repeater but this should not impact on the solution.

---

**UPDATE**

Using flex model as noted by `Paran0a` I have got to this stage using a tiny script to calculate the height of `.Wrap` However it's hard to calculate half the width correclty as the last box could be huge.

```
var h = 0;
$('.Wrap > div').each(function() {
    $(this).height(Math.random()*100);        
    h += $(this).height();        
});
$('.Wrap').height((h/2));
```

[DEMO UPDATE](https://jsfiddle.net/oLzw742p/5/)

Comment: isn't it just a case for column-count: 2 ?

Comment: @vals could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you be able to support `flex-box`?

Here's a little demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/oLzw742p/3/

```js
$(function(){
var test = [],
    num = 1,
     randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 2;
for (i = 1; i <= randomNo; i++) {
    test[i] = $('.Wrap').append('<div class="A'+(i)+'">A'+(i)+'</div>');
};
$('.Wrap > div').each(function() {
    $(this).height(Math.random()*100);
});
});
```

```css
.Wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.Wrap > div {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.Wrap div:nth-child(5n+1) {background: blue;}
.Wrap div:nth-child(5n+2) {background: red;}
.Wrap div:nth-child(5n+3) {background: green;}
.Wrap div:nth-child(5n+4) {background: purple;}
.Wrap div:nth-child(5n+5) {background: black;}
```

```html
<div class="Wrap"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by variable? Their height can be whatever you wan't , they will overflow to next column accordingly.

Comment: Why are you changing height of the wrapper randomly? Whats the point of that? I can only guess that it was by mistake. Here mine + your demo https://jsfiddle.net/oLzw742p/3/

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have the same code in your production? You're generating random height?

Comment: But you will have some kind of height, right? And when that height is set , if the elements don't fit anymore they will overflow in new column.

Comment: I managed to make this into a workable solution thanks for your help. It would be helpful to others to adjust your answer to be like your second example jsfiddle.net/oLzw742p/3